# Why "lsmod | wc -l" not equal "ls /sys/module | wc -l"

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

Why do these two commands return different results?

```
lsmod | wc -l
100

ls /sys/module | wc -l
138
```

Answer (score 13):

`lsmod` lists all of your *dynamic* modules that are loaded.

The entries in `/sys/module` correspond to dynamic modules *and* modules which are built into the kernel (and have parameters that need to be accessible) rather than loaded dynamically. For example:

```
[michael@brazzers:~]$ ls -d /sys/module/ip_tables/
/sys/module/ip_tables/
[michael@brazzers:~]$ lsmod |grep ^ip_tables
ip_tables              26995  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
[michael@brazzers:~]$ grep CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4 /boot/config-3.8.0-30-generic
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4=m
```

You can see here that the iptables module is configured as a dynamic module. Contrast to:

```
[michael@brazzers:~]$ ls -d /sys/module/apparmor/
/sys/module/apparmor/
[michael@brazzers:~]$ lsmod |grep ^apparmor
[michael@brazzers:~]$ grep APPARMOR /boot/config-3.8.0-30-generic 
CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR=y
```

whereas apparmor is built-in.

Comment: @MikeB when you see CONFIG_X_X=yes i think that means the code is builting in the kernel not as dinamic module: Example grep EXT4 /boot/config-3.6.11-4.fc16.i686 
CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y
  modinfo ext4
ERROR: Module ext4 not found  ls -l /sys/module/ext4
ls: cannot access /sys/module/ext4: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, it looks as though built-in modules [need to have parameters](http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/What-is-listed-in-sys-module-td657227.html) for them to be visible.

Answer (score 5):

- `/sys/module/MODULENAME`

`MODULENAME` is the name of the module that is in the kernel. This module name will always show up if the module is loaded as a dynamic module. This is exactly what you can see when you issue `lsmod` command or when you check `/proc/modules` file.

If it is built directly into the kernel it will only show up if it has a version or at least one parameter. The available parameters are then available in the directory:

- `/sys/module/MODULENAME/parameters`